# Could there be a better explanation for other people's behavior?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, argumentation

Can there be a better explanation of other people's behavior than that offered by the best explanation argument?

The argument says that the best explanation for the behavior we observe in other people is that other people have minds.

Could there be a better explanation of other people's behavior that does not involve other minds?

Or will the best explanation for other people's behavior always be that other people also have minds?

Comment: Yes. It will be.

Comment: how are you going to improve on its elegance?

Comment: our "interpretation" of other people behavior is based on the assumption that they are "like us". We use this assumption to comunicate with them.

Comment: I did not understand anything from this

Comment: "*A mind is a terrible thing to waste.*" So let's not "explain by explaining away."

Comment: I've always wondered why there are not more hard solipsists.

Comment: There is a tv show Westworld, where a character starts noticing that people around her live out the stories she invents. If *that* were to happen in the future one would need to start looking for a better explanation. Otherwise, such ponderings are idle and unproductive.

Comment: @BillOnne maybe most of them are hypnoticized in some sifi thus hard to realize so in a critical philosophical reflective sense, like according to Idries Shah?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does science have any separate arguments for the existence of other minds?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/93684/does-science-have-any-separate-arguments-for-the-existence-of-other-minds)

Answer (score 1):

You want to throw baby out with the bath water? But you need some thing to explain your world. Other minds clearly exist, and their difference from you does not multiply the sort of things that there are.

Beware magnets.

Comment: sorry that was entirely facetious of me

Comment: "Other minds clearly exist, and their difference from you does not multiply the sort of things that there are." - What does it mean?

Comment: any word in particular @Johnny5454 ?

Comment: "and their difference from you does not multiply the sort of things that there are."- What does it mean?

Comment: an explanation involving just lots of electrons all acting in the same way is more elegant than an explanation involving several fundamental particles, even if they are less numerous. that's all I mean... pretty sure that's how Occam's razor is meant to work, though perhaps not ; )

Comment: explain it with the example of other minds please